# Reverting but keeping a mod-only tag impossible

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, rollbacks, moderator-tags

User A posts a question.

User B edits it.

Mod C adds a mod-only tag.

User A doesn't like user B's edit, so clicks "edit" next to the original revision, edits in the same tag mod C had added, and tries to save.

He'll be told he can't, as the tag is mod-only.

This appears to be a bug: the software should allow an edit that keeps the current tags.

Comment: The problem is the system is reverting the mod's edit too (you're erasing everything back to that point). You're editing a version *before* that tag existed. It doesn't combine the mod's edit into that version for you.

Comment: @animuson, but the system can know the diff between A's reedit and C's edit, so can know the tags haven't changed.

Comment: That's asking a bit much of the system.  Just edit revision c instead of revision b.  This is not Git.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, note that A is reediting revision A, not revision B, in the example.

Comment: @msh210: You're looking at this the wrong way. When you have revisions A, B, and C, you can't revise A and treat it like a revision to C, **it's a revision to A**. You're trying to make the system believe that you're modifying C, which has the tag. But in reality you're editing A, which *doesn't* have the tag and you don't have permission to add it in.

Comment: This is not a Version Control system. What's wrong with just modifying rev c? If you're after editing a specific revision in the revision history, it doesn't work that way; users are not allowed to change history. An edit to any revision other than the current one create a new revision that *throws out all of the edits in any revisions after the one being edited.*

Comment: @animuson: In reality, you're editing the question. No?

Comment: @msh210: When I'm editing one alternate reality, I'm editing the universe, no?

Comment: @animuson, sorry, my rep on scifi.se is 0.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, re the edited-in "An edit to any revision other than the current one create a new revision that throws out all of the edits in any revisions after the one being edited": They don't show up in revision history any longer? I thought they did....

Comment: I didn't say it throws out the revision history; it throws out any edits that happened after the selected revision when creating the new revision. In other words, editing revision A forks revision A, not revision C. The new revision knows nothing about the edits that occurred in revision B or C.

Comment: My background isn't Git (which you, @RobertHarvey, mentioned earlier) but Mediawiki. There, it's possible to "edit an old revision" but you're in fact just using the old revision as your basis point but editing the page, and in the revision list your edit shows up as a diff from the next most recent revision. That seems so much more natural than the way revisions work here (and would allow the "readdition" of a mod-only tag, as I'm asking about here), but perhaps it's just my Mediawiki-influenced bias showing....

Comment: Perhaps I should remove the [meta-tag:bug] tag and add [meta-tag:feature-request] instead?

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. Don't try to edit the *original* revision, click "edit" next to the *current* revision.

The problem is that you don't have privileges to add moderator-only tags, that's why you can't edit the original revision and add it in yourself.

However, you *can* still edit the content/body of the post without touching the moderator-added tags. To do that, you need to click the "edit" link next to the current revision, the one *after* the moderator has made his/her edit.

So it's not a bug. The system *does* allow edits that keeps the current tags, as long as you initiate the edit from a revision that actually contains those tags.

Comment: But (a) this requires editing the original revision to copy it (and not save) and then editing the current revision to paste the original revision, which is a pain in the neck, and, more importantly, (b) doesn't seem reasonable: all I'm doing is editing the question. Why should what revision I'm starting with affect anything?

Comment: @msh: Right, that's the point. Don't just copy and paste your original question back in. The edits that were made were obviously made for a reason. If you'd like to improve on them further, well then that's encouraged. But copying and pasting your original question back in, ignoring the edits that were made, is very likely to get your post locked altogether, preventing you from making *any* edits. As for your second argument, I already explained in detail why the revision that you're starting with affects things. You don't have the privileges to add moderator-only tags.

Comment: That would be the way to do it, yes. In my experience, the need to do this is rare, though. In most cases, the current revision is the one to start with. If you're uncomfortable with the copy/paste, just rollback the edit you don't like. The moderator tag still disappears, though.

Comment: @CodyGray, as to my 2nd question, no, you explained *how* (by what technical means) the revision I'm starting from affects things, not *why* it should do so. As I said, it seems unreasonable that it should do so, as all I'm doing is editing the question.

Comment: It doesn't seem unreasonable to me. By starting from an earlier revision, you're effectively rolling back to that point in time. You're allowed to do that, but the normal rules apply: you can't add moderator-only tags. Different version control systems work different ways, the only real point is having one that works predictably.

Comment: Wait: does that mean I can remove mod-only tags by editing a older revision of a question? (Should I try that? Would that be abuse?)